# NHibernate Component Mapping VS IUserType

Tags: nhibernate

Hi I would like to know the difference between the two and why should you use one over the other and when?

Answer (score 2):

Your object model doesn't necessarily map one to one to your database model and in most cases will be richer. Components are a way of enriching your database model by encapsulating functionality in your object model. For example lets say you have two tables, `people` and `companies`. Both of these tables have the fields required for an `address`, but the database schema, for whatever reason, doesn't have a third table for `addresses`. In your application you might want to model addresses as a separate entity even though there is no logical database table for it. Here you would use a component which would allow you to project the database fields for an address.

`IUserType` is a way of mapping a type to a column using a custom serialization. For example if you were to map a mongodb `ObjectId` (which is nothing more than a guid), you could write a custom `IUserType` to do the mapping. Other examples could be mapping a bit mask to an array of rich user types or encoding/decoding an encrypted field.